# How do I edit a Shopify Web Hook?

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I need to have the Shopify Web Hook parsed in the way I want it to look myself, I want it to HTTP POST only a few lines of information that are taken from the order that the Web Hook will be sent for.

I work with third parties that need order information that I send to them, these third parties have to adapt in 1 way or another to the web hooks but as of right now Web Hooks looks fairly limiting. Is there any way I can edit the contents of a web hook through the Shopify API???

I want to make use of the Web Hooks but be able to use it as a regular HTTP POST mechanism where I can choose myself exactly what I will send to the link I set to have the information sent to.

Answer (score 3):

It works like this.

Shopify sends you an Order via Webhook. It's not sophisticated computing. They just keep on sending the complete order to your URL endpoint until you return a 200 OK status that you got it or they just give up on you.

Now that you have the entire order, you parse it, take out only the note stuff you want, and now YOU can send just your precious note stuff to your favorite person via HTTP POST using your computing engine... be it some PHP, Python, Ruby, Java or .Net concoction.

Shopify ==(order)==> Your App (you process)   ===> do what you want...